# STDisjoint() = not STIntersects()?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

In short, are `STDisjoint()` and `STIntersects()` antipodes of each other?
According to the documentation, it seems that they are. But there is no explicit note about it.

Are there any tricks? Which one is faster, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, disjoint = not intersects.

As to which is faster, according to the documentation on spatial indexes at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265.aspx#methods , a spatial index can be used for a query containing `geometry1.STIntersects(geometry2) = 1`.

Strangely enough, `geometry1.STDisjoint(geometry2) = 0` is not listed.

Comment: It seems that I miss something in the mathematical definitions of these operations. Could you provide a link to materials about them? BTW thx for the answer. Indexing is quite important in my task.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets

Comment: @Colin'tHart Probably for the same reason that `column = @X` can use an index while `column <> @X` usually doesn't.